# How to Load Ext Js Tab after cliclking it

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I got a Ext JS block of code generating 4 tabs:

Javascript:

```
var tabs;
$(document).ready( function() {
            fullscreen: true,
            renderTo: 'tabs1',
            width:900,
            activeTab: 0,
            frame:true,
            defaults:{autoHeight: true},
            items:[
                {contentEl:'AutoOrJudgemental', title: 'Tab 1 '},
                {contentEl:'CreditRequestQueues', title: 'Tab 2' },
                {contentEl:'ApplicationStatistics', title: 'Tab3'},
                {contentEl:'RequestStatus', title: 'Tab4'}
            ],
            listeners: {
                activeitemchange: function (tabs1) {
                    alert(tabs1.id);
                }
            }
    });

});
```

```
                                            var myChart = new FusionCharts( "/sbm/bpmportal/FusionCharts/Doughnut3D.swf", "myChartId-AutoOrJudgemental", "100%", "420", "0", "0" );

                                            myChart.setJSONData(respArr[0]);
                                            myChart.render("AutoOrJudgemental");

                                            myChart = new FusionCharts( "/sbm/bpmportal/FusionCharts/Column3D.swf", 
                                                    "myChartId-CreditRequestQueues", "100%", "420", "0" );

                                  xmlhttp.open("GET","/sbm/bpmportal/pages/ICDPDashBoard.do?drFrom="+fromDateStr+"&drTo="+toDateStr,true);
                                xmlhttp.send();
                            }
                            </script>
```

Can any one suggest a way to load the data in the tab only after we click it
By default data in all the tabs are getting loaded.

Iam using Ajax call to get the data and displaying the chart using Fusion charts

```
 <p class="text">&nbsp; </p>
<div id="tabs1" style="float: left; width: 100%">               <div id="simple-int" class="x-hide-display"
style="float: left; width: 100%">
    <span id="AutoOrJudgemental"> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not valid code.

Comment: Please display all your code and perhaps show a jsfiddle.net of your work - as @EvanTrimboli said it currently is not valid code.

Comment: The code is workrking

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know the result:

[ExtJS Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2ga)

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    id: 'sample-tab',
    activeTab: 0,
    items: [
        {
            title: 'TAB A',
            bodyPadding : 10,
            html: 'Tab A Sample Content'
        },
        {
            title: 'TAB B',
            bodyPadding : 10,
            loader: {
                url: 'http://www.google.com.tr',
                contentType: 'html',
                loadMask: true
            },
            listeners: {
                activate: function(tab) {
                    tab.loader.load();
                }
            }
        },
        {
            title: 'TAB C',
            bodyPadding : 10,
            html: 'Tab C Sample Content'
        }
    ],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });    
})
```